# Make URL inaccessible for everything but a specific Webpage

Tags: php, .htaccess, access-control

For a file transfer system, I store data on my server. The data can be accessed using a URL, for example:

```
http://filestorage.example.com/files/clientfiles/clientid/test.pdf
```

All files inside the folder clientid/ are linked on a generated download page for the client, For example:

```
http://example.com/download.php?clientid=28692692846
```

Above URL contains a webpage with multiple links to all files inside the clientid folder:

```
<a href="http://filestorage.example.com/files/clientfiles/clientid/test.pdf" download>
test.pdf
</a>
```

Now I want to restrict the access to the files. It should be impossible to access the files from outside, they should only be accessible from the download.php.
Is it even possible to achieve something like this?

Files and the script are on the same server.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way I can think of to accomplish this would be to use a unique session variable generated on the files inside the /clientid folder - regardless of what the file extension is for these, they'd be simple PHP pages which loaded the files via download.php.

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['file_id'] = $secret_file_id;
header("Location: http://example.com/download.php?clientid=28692692846");
```

Then in the download.php file, check for this variable.

```
session_start();
if((isset($_SESSION['file_id'])) && ($_SESSION['file_id'] == $secret_file_id)) {
    // Offer file for download
} else {
    //Not referred from correct URL, reject.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put a `.htaccess` file in that folder that contains just:

```
deny from all
```

In this way you cannot open any file from that folder, but you can include them in php without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can achieve this through `.htaccess` using:

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from example.com/download.php
```

This will deny everyone access unless they visit via `example.com/download.php`.

If you're using Apache 2.4, then you would need to use:

```
Require all denied
Require host example.com/download.php
```

Obviously you would need to place the `.htaccess` file into the folder that you wish to restrict access too. So if I'm understanding your file structure correctly that would be `/clientid/`